# Insert more stuff in an XML loaded Layout

Tags: android

I'm using `setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);` to load an XML to my activity.
On this layout, there is a `FrameLayout`, I want to insert more objects in it dynamically, as an example, more `Button` Objects.

I haven't found some getCurrentView() method yet... So, how can I get the current Layout from the activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, assign an id to your FrameLayout in the XML:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/MyFrameLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Then, you can access any inflated Views in your `Activity` after calling `setContentView()` by using `findViewById()` in conjunction with the automatically generated `R.java`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.MyFrameLayout);
```

`findViewById()` will search recursively, so regardless where your `FrameLayout` is, it will be found (as long as there isn't a duplicate id somewhere else in the XML, which you should avoid).

From there, just create the Button dynamically and add it as a child of the `FrameLayout`:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
layout.addView(button);
```